# How to change color in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hey guys I just created a application in android studio. In menu bar there is "more options" I created but it is not clearly visible it's color is white I want black. How to change that color check out screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPGYj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is your Menu in the ActionBar of the activity? If so, you can change the color of the ActionBar in styles.xml